# What is difference between match and bool must match query in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, booleanquery

What is the difference between Only **match and bool must match query** in ES?

First, Only use the match query

```
{
   "query":{
      "match":{
         "address":"mill"
      }
   }
}
```

[image]

Second, use compound query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match": { "address": "mill" } }
      ]
     }
   }
}
```

[image]

Can you tell me everything?
What is difference between them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you use only one `match` inside a `bool must` clause then there is no difference, the bool clause is useful when you want to combine multiple(boolean) criteria, more info on [official ES doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html#query-dsl-bool-query). It supports below criteria.

1. must
2. must_not
3. filter
4. should

Let me show by taking a small example from your question.

### Index mapping with just address and first_name

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "address": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "first_name" :{
                "type" : "text"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Index 3 docs, all having same address `mill`, but different `first_name`

```
{
   "address" : "mill",
   "first_name" : "Johnson"
}

{
   "address" : "mill",
   "first_name" : "Parker"
}

{
   "address" : "mill",
   "first_name" : "opster"
}
```

### Search query to show all adresses of `mill` but must_not contain first_name as `parker`

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "address": "mill"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "must_not": {
                        "first_name": "parker"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

### Result only 2 address

```
"hits": [
         {
            "_index": "so-60620921-bool",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 0.13353139,
            "_source": {
               "address": "mill",
               "first_name": "opster"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "so-60620921-bool",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 0.13353139,
            "_source": {
               "address": "mill",
               "first_name": "Johnson"
            }
         }
      ]
```

**Based on the OP comments, providing the [query and filter context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html), to understand the performance aspects in details.**

Comment: Thanks! Can 'match' and 'must not' be written in the same depth?

Comment: That `must_not` query is completely new to me ;-) `no [query] registered for [must_not]` it should be at the same level as `must`

Comment: @Val, Sorry was on mobile and read it as `must` and `must_not` :), thanks for pointing this out :)

Comment: @Johnson, Added query and filter context link, which would help to understand, how these queries work internally and affect the performance.

Comment: @Johnson, please refer @val comment on your `Can 'match' and 'must not' be written in the same depth` query.

Answer (score 2):

As written in your question, they will perform the same action.

The `match` query is a very straight forward full-text condition statement.

The [bool](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) query allows you to add multiple fields and multiple conditions such as [exists](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html) (to validate a certain field is found in the documents), `should` (an OR equivalent) and `must_not` (a NOT equivalent).

Taking again your example, since the `bool` query only has a single `must, match` condition, it will only return all the documents with the value `mill` contained in the `address` field.

Hope this is helpful! :)

Comment: Thanks. I think they have difference like performance.. or anything else..

Comment: @Johnson, for your given case, there is no difference in performance, but id you add `filter` in your `bool` clause, then it makes a big difference in performance, as Elasticsearch first execute the filters(which makes fewer documents to search)  and then excute the search on remaining documents, on top of that, filters are cached , which means next time same query will be much faster.

Comment: Yes. Filter for the win :)