# How to use 'not' to filter terms in Elastic Search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to Elastic Search and can't find information on how to use `not` or `must_not` as term filter with elastic search.

My query is set up as follows:

```json
        {
            "size":4,
            "from":0,
            "query":{
                "bool":{
                    "filter":[
                        {
                            "term":{
                                "published":1
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "term":{
                                "brand.keyword":"Honda"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "not": {
                                "term": {
                                    "tags": "Red"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "wildcard":{
                                "image":"*"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
```

But when I test in Postman I get the error:

```
 "type": "parsing_exception",
 "reason": "no [query] registered for [not]"
```

Would anyone know how I could fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60646098/what-is-difference-between-match-query-and-bool-must-match-query/60646944#60646944 this also gives some more information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the `filter` clause works as a `must` clause. The difference between the two is only that any query inside the filter clause will not be influencing the score of the document or in other words for the `filter` clause, the score is not calculated whereas for `must`, `must_not` and `should` the score will be calculated. This is known as [filter context and query context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/query-filter-context.html).

Now if you don't want `must_not` to be part of score calculation then the query will be:

```
{
  "size": 4,
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "published": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "brand.keyword": "Honda"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "tags": "Red"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "image": "*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this gets rid of the error but does not affect the results

Comment: @MeltingDog Please add index mapping, sample docs and expected result for more clarity. You can add it here in the same question or write up a separate question for the same.

Comment: I think I got it. Since the tags were an array I needed to use `"tags.keyword": "Red"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `must_not` clauses directly because they are executed in [filter context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html) meaning that scoring is ignored and clauses are considered for caching. Exactly like `filter` clauses and therefore differently from the `must` and `should` clauses.

Here is the [boolean query documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html).

Here is your query:

```json
{
  "size": 4,
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "published": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "brand.keyword": "Honda"
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "image": "*"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "tags.keyword": "Red"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```